# getting string values from 4 spinners - error with listener

Tags: android

I hope you can help/advise
I wrote a simple shift calc for my GF and I stupidly agreed to port to her phone.phone. Im 3 days into Android coding so be gentle with me :)

Shift calc has 4 spinners
SOSH - start of shift hour
SOSM - minute
EOSH - end of shift hour
EOSM - minute

Im not even sure if Im over complicating what I need:

user selects the 4 values from the spinners and I will pass to joda Time for calculation.

So far I have one spinner SOSH working and tested by passing the string to textview and all was Ok. SO added SOSM to the mix and now with two listeners its causing problems.

Do I even need this as i dont care when a spinner is changed , I just need to retrieve the values once the button is pressed.

heres what i have - any advice really welcome

// code for SOSH and SOSM spinner **********************************************************************************************************************************

```
            Spinner  spinnerSOSH = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSOSH);
            Spinner  spinnerSOSM = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSOSM);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSOSH = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.StringArraySOSH,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSOSH.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSOSH.setAdapter(adapterSOSH);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSOSM = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.StringArraySOSM,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSOSM.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSOSM.setAdapter(adapterSOSM);

    spinnerSOSH.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()); // error: Error:(41, 47) error: OnItemSelectedListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated
    spinnerSOSM.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()

    {
```

//Do the string conversion for SOSH and store in SOSH string

```
            Spinner spinnerSOSH = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSOSH);
            String SOSHString = spinnerSOSH.getSelectedItem().toString();

            //Do the string conversion for SOSM and store in SOSM string 

            Spinner spinnerSOSM = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSOSM);
            String SOSMString = spinnerSOSM.getSelectedItem().toString();



        @Override
        void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // error : Error:(61, 18) error: onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>,View,int,long) in <anonymous com.welfareindustries.jennisshiftcalc2.MainActivity$1> cannot implement onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>,View,int,long) in OnItemSelectedListener
            //attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public





        //////////////// taost message the value///////////////

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                    "On Item Select : \n" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//change a text box to the value///////////////////
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StringValueText);
            textView.setText(SOSMString);
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

got it guys, i KNEW i was over complicating

```
            Spinner spinnerSOSH = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSOSH);
            String SOSHVal = spinnerSOSH.getSelectedItem().toString();

            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SOSHText);
            textView.setText(SOSHVal);



            Spinner spinnerSOSM = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSOSM);
            String SOSMVal = spinnerSOSM.getSelectedItem().toString();

            final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SOSMtext);
            textView1.setText(SOSMVal);





            Spinner spinnerEOSH = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerEOSH);
            String EOSHVal= spinnerEOSH.getSelectedItem().toString();

            final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EOSHText);
            textView2.setText(EOSHVal);




            Spinner spinnerEOSM = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerEOSM);
            String EOSMVal= spinnerEOSM.getSelectedItem().toString();

            final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EOSMText);
            textView3.setText(EOSMVal);
```